# how to reverse the order of words of one language using css when there are 2 languages used?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a website with the possibility of using either English or Arabic language. When the language is Arabic, I need some words to remain English.

For Arabic, I use

```
direction: rtl;
```

As an example for the following sentence,

```
مرحبا: Prabhashi (NEW) أهلا بك
```

the result by rtl is as follows,

[image]

But I need the result to be,

```
    أهلا بك (NEW) Prabhashi :مرحبا
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi

Comment: Which result actually you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve your problem. It iterates over the string, adds all the words in the strings separated by a " " into an array and then reverses it

```
function reverse_sentence(str){
str += " ";
var words = [];
var last_break = 0,word_length = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == " "){
       var word = str.substr(last_break, word_length);
      words.push(word);
      last_break = i + 1;
      word_length = 0;
    }else{
        word_length++;
    }
  } 
  return words.reverse();
}

alert(reverse_sentence("Hi my name is Albin"));
```

Comment: This is a very specific solution. What if there were commas or other such characters?

Comment: You could write a util function for the comparison str[I] == " " to compare it to an array of chars. Just wanted to help him out getting a start on how to do it.

Comment: Yes but the amount of such characters, especially including languages other than English is too high. Are you expecting OP to add an if statement for every character?

Comment: Why would you have to write individual IF-stmts? You could as mentioned just fill an array with break points and compare in a for-loop

Comment: That's just another way of dodging the original problem. My point being, how prudent is it to manually add every known special character from every LTR and RTL language?

Answer (score 0):

I think as per the link: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

You will have to add this character after your brackets to tell the browser that it should be LTR. Like the example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="unicode">
</head>
<body>
  <div dir="rtl">
     مرحبا: Prabhashi (NEW)&#x200E; أهلا بك
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this will be the simplest answer for your problem.